# Turn off Anti-Aliasing on Mac

Tags: mac, screen-capture, color

This is a followup to the Stack Overflow question, [Why does there appear to be a different number of unique colors available on the Mac as compared to Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087658/why-does-there-appear-to-be-a-different-number-of-unique-colors-available-on-the)

How can I turn off anti-aliasing on a Mac, either through manual settings or, more preferably, while doing a screen capture (i.e., when I capture the screen, I need the raw data without anti-aliasing algorithms applied)?

Answer (score 3):

You can manually turn off font-antialiasing with this terminal command:

```
defaults write CoreGraphics CGFontDisableAntialiasing YES
```

to turn antialiasing back on again use this:

```
defaults write CoreGraphics CGFontDisableAntialiasing NO
```

Comment: Thanks for Quick response. Even with Anti Aliasing OFF, i see around 250 different colors for small block of text. Is there any way to get less unique colors for same block, as On Windows it shows only 2 colors for same block with Anti Aliasing Off. Appreciate your quick responses.

Answer (score 0):

Does the `Command` + `Option` + `\` helps?

This option keys disable the Anti Aliasing when doing the Zoom (using Ctrl + Scroll)